# How to check login is successful fron curl in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have written a php script to login to a site from curl. Below is my code:

```
<?php
// INIT CURL
$ch = curl_init();

// SET URL FOR THE POST FORM LOGIN
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://wordpress.dev/wp-login.php');

// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// SET POST PARAMETERS : FORM VALUES FOR EACH FIELD
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'log=admin&pwd=admin');

// IMITATE CLASSIC BROWSER'S BEHAVIOUR : HANDLE COOKIES
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

# Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
# not to print out the results of its query.
# Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
# from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// EXECUTE 1st REQUEST (FORM LOGIN)
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($store);exit;

// CLOSE CURL
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

If I give right password it gives string() "  and if give wrong password it redirects me to the login page 
How can check that login is successful?

Comment: curl_exec return string tells you the result.

Comment: if you got an answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check response code as well. This might help you.

```
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

var_dump($httpcode);
var_dump($contents);
```

In most cases HTTP code 200 is a valid authentication.

Comment: here is output of 
var_dump($httpcode);
var_dump($contents);
int(302) 
bool(true)

Comment: means that 302 http code you are getting, which means you need redirection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302 you are getting another URL in header to redirect.

Comment: In my case www.gmail.com redirects me to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2

Comment: actually I am trying to login to another account not in gmail

Answer (score 1):

**[curl_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)** Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

```
<?php 

     //execute the request (the login)
     $store = curl_exec($ch);    

     if($store){ //check for true/false
         //Logged in
     }else{
         //Login failed
     }

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

if you are on HTTPS, add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

add this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: I posted my whole scipt in the post. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

you can check it with `$store` it will return true on success otherwise false.

check [Storing the response of login using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564857/storing-the-response-of-login-using-curl) . think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to status codes.

curl_exec would return true even if your login is not validated.

It simply means that the curl request is executed without error..

Make sure that status code is "200"..